# Surge in views for question

Tags: discussion, questions

I have asked a relative low number of question on Stack Overflow and have been able to keep track of these easily as a result.

I noticed that one of my questions has received a couple of hundred results in the last month or so.

The question is very unimportant. I am not going to link it here. If really want to see the question, you will be able to find it.

Anyways, has anyone else experienced this large surge in question views and what could it be down to? Can bots view pages or is there someone sitting on the page clicking refresh. I am aware of what makes a good question on Stack Overflow and the one I am referring to is not one.

Or do some questions with certain tags receive consistently more page views than other tags.

Comment: you got more views because.... more people than before clicked on your question :). Short of that (or mind reading), what kind of answer do you really expect?

Comment: Good man @Patrice, good man!

Comment: Have you shared a link for it anywhere (or has someone else?) We can only guess, here.

Comment: Some tags ARE more active than others.... so maybe?

Comment: ....and then their friends will share the question with their other friends and those friends will share it with their other friends....

Comment: @Patrice your answers make me smile.... and yes OP, ryanyuyu is right, cause sharing is caring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. I have noticed that sometimes too. Some reasons that come in mind:

- Google ranks your question high. I have experienced this myself since one of my questions regarding a new HTML5 element is ranked third in Google when you just use a very general query on "html5 datetime". The question gets views quite easily through that since people tend to view the first few items Google gives them.
- It is also possible your raised a question on Meta regarding your question or one of the answers. Or maybe you were subject yourself of a discussion here which will result in people checking out your profile and your posts.
- You have shared your question through some social media or StackOverflow did that through their own Twitter question feed. (This is visible in the post history)
- Your question was used as a duplicate close target.

There are probably other reasons but these were the first I could think of.

Comment: Some questions get attention for (un)clear reasons on reddit/hackernews/quora. So it doesn't need the OP to share the link. Maybe the question was mentioned in the newsletter. Maybe it was mentioned in chat.

Comment: Looks like you could be on to something here, my question is also ranked high by Google for a general search. I will keep this open for another while. I would be surprised if it was one of the other reasons you mentioned.

Comment: I think its perfectly plausible that I have received the surge in views due to the Google rank of my question. Thanks.

Comment: Also, there's a newsletter?! Gimme.